# How to use pandas to pull out the counties with the largest amount of water used in a given year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and pandas and I am struggling to figure out how to pull out the 10 counties with the most water used for irrigation in 2014.

```
%matplotlib inline
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('info.csv') #reads csv

data['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(['Year'], format='%Y') #converts string to 
                                                     datetime
data.index = data['Year'] #makes year the index
del data['Year'] #delete the duplicate year column
```

This is what the data looks like (this is only partial of the data):

```
County  WUCode  RegNo   Year    SourceCode  SourceID    Annual    CountyName 
1       IR      311     2014    WELL        1           946       Adams  
1       IN      311     2014    INTAKE      1           268056    Adams
1       IN      312     2014    WELL        1           48        Adams
1       IN      312     2014    WELL        2           96        Adams
1       IR      312     2014    INTAKE      1           337968    Adams
3       IR      315     2014    WELL        5           81900     Putnam
3       PS      315     2014    WELL        6           104400    Putnam
```

I have a couple questions:

I am not sure how to pull out only the "IR" in the `WUCode` Column with pandas and I am not sure how to print out a table with the 10 counties with the highest water usage for irrigation in 2014.

I have been able to use the `.loc` function to pull out the information I need, with something like this:

```
data.loc['2014', ['CountyName', 'Annual', 'WUCode']]
```

From here I am kind of lost. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about `df[df["Year"] == 2014].sort_values("Annual", axis=1, ascending=False).head(10)` ? (I'm just not sure that Year will be equal to 2014 as it is a datetime)

Comment: I think a `groupby` is required first, as each county has multiple result for 2014 for WUCode = 'IR'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Annual": np.random.randint(20, 1000000, 1000),
                "Year": np.random.randint(2012, 2016, 1000),
                "CountyName": np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), 1000)},
              columns=["Annual", "Year", "CountyName"])
```

Say df looks like:

```
   Annual  Year CountyName
0  518966  2012          s
1   44511  2013          E
2  332010  2012          e
3  382168  2013          c
4  202816  2013          y
```

For the year 2014...

```
df[df['Year'] == 2014]
```

Group by CountyName...

```
df[df['Year'] == 2014].groupby("CountyName")
```

Look at Annual...

```
df[df['Year'] == 2014].groupby("CountyName")["Annual"]
```

Get the sum...

```
df[df['Year'] == 2014].groupby("CountyName")["Annual"].sum()
```

Sort the result descending...

```
df[df['Year'] == 2014].groupby("CountyName")["Annual"].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Take the top 10...

```
df[df['Year'] == 2014].groupby("CountyName")["Annual"].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
```

This example prints out (your actual result may vary since my data was random):

```
CountyName
Q    5191814
y    4335358
r    4315072
f    3985170
A    3685844
a    3583360
S    3301817
I    3231621
t    3228578
u    3164965
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
res = df[df['WUCode'] == 'IR'].groupby(['Year', 'CountyName'])['Annual'].sum()\
                              .reset_index()\
                              .sort_values('Annual', ascending=False)\
                              .head(10)

#    Year CountyName  Annual
# 0  2014      Adams  338914
# 1  2014     Putnam   81900
```

**Explanation**

- Filter by WUCode, as required, and `groupby` Year and CountyName.
- Use `reset_index` so your result is a dataframe rather than a series.
- Use `sort_values` and extract top 10 via `pd.DataFrame.head`.